# Sass compile and create comments on what changed

Tags: html, css, sass

I was wondering if there is anyway to compile a scss file to css and inside the css file are comments that tell you what changed in the scss.

It might look something like this:

```
/* line 9, ../sass/foundation/components/_global.scss */
html,{}
```

I just recently started working with sass and the person previously who did the sass compiling used compass. I read somewhere that it involves the config.rb but I can't find this file. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you want to track changes you should use versioning software such as Git, Mercurial, or Subversion. If you want to track where the styles were generated from, some SASS compilers allow for source maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Sass Reference](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#line_numbers-option), the correct option is `:line_numbers` – you want to set that to `true`. That will generate comments with the format in your question.

How to set that option that depends on how you are compiling your Sass. [Installing Compass](http://compass-style.org/install/) would set up a configuration file `config.rb` in which you [could write](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/) `line_numbers = true`. If you're just using the `sass` command-line tool, there is a command-line switch to enable the option, according to `sass --help`. You can use the command `sass --line-numbers` to compile with that option enabled.